# Pause UI thread until backgroundworker finishes

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a treeview which includes directory information. I have a btnMoveFiles_click event which calls a background worker to move some files, as I am using a progress bar. Once completed, the treeview is rebuilt using a second backgroundworker, in case folders have been created. The last step is for the initial node in the treeview to be reselected. For this I use a recursive script and find by fullpath using the following code:

```
    private void selectCurrentNode()
    {
        tvSourceDirectories.SelectedNode = GetNode(currentFullPath);            
    }
    private TreeNode GetNode(string FullPath, TreeNode rootNode)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in rootNode.Nodes)
        {
            if (node.FullPath.Equals(FullPath)) return node;

            //recursion
            var next = GetNode(FullPath, node);
            if (next != null) return next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private TreeNode GetNode(string FullPath)
    {
        TreeNode itemNode = null;
        foreach (TreeNode node in tvSourceDirectories.Nodes)
        {
            if (node.FullPath.Equals(FullPath)) return node;

            itemNode = GetNode(FullPath, node);
            if (itemNode != null) break;
        }
        return itemNode;
    }
```

My problem is that it works perfectly for less complex directory structures, but if there are too many folders, the correct node is not selected. While debugging, it appears that the selectCurrentNode() method isrunning before the backgroundworker is completed and no nodes are returned so the method has no effect. If I attach the method to a separate button event and allow time for the treeview to rebuild, it works perfectly. It appears to be a timing issue.
Is there a way to pause the ui thread in the btnMoveFiles_click event to wait for the backgroundworker to complete treeview rebuild.
Although I have not have any issues thus far, it may be that I will have a similar problem with the second backgroundworker commencing before the move files backgroundworker has completed(if many files to process). I could, and did initially have the call to the second background worker within the runworkercompleted of the first, but still doesn't solve the main problem which is the selectCurrentNode() firing before the backgroundworkeer is completed.
Effectively I need a way to stop any further processing which involves the ui until the individual backgroundworkers have completed.
I have not included the backgroundworker code as didn't think it was relevant to the question but can do so if required.
Thanks

The click event is as follows and the selectCurrentNode() runs before the others are completed.

```
private void btnMoveFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   bgwMoveFiles.RunWorkerAsync();
   bgwGetSourceTV.RunWorkerAsync();
   selectCurrentNode()
}
```

Comment: "the backgroundworker code" is the only relevant code. There is nothing async here now.

Comment: You cannot block the UI thread.  Many problems with it, but the most typical result is that your program will deadlock.  The RunWorkerCompleted event cannot run with a blocked UI thread.  You need to move the code that now appears after the "wait until done" code into that event handler.  Use the Enabled property of your UI object(s) to prevent the user from inappropriately activate code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will move the "wait until done" code to the RunWorkerCompleted as suggested. I think my error has been putting them in the click event and although I tried putting them both in the Movefiles RunWorkeCompleted, I think I need to separate them. and put selectCurrentNode() in the treeviewrebuild RunWorkerCompleted. That way I am assuming these tasks won't overlap